# Quadratic programming with positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Let us consider the following optimization problem
$$
\min \,\,\, (1/2)x^{T}Px + q^{T}x
$$
$$
\text{subject to} \quad Ax \in C
$$
where $C$ is a closed convex set.

Assume now that $p$ is positive semidefinite matrix. Therefore, the solution might not be unique.

Next, according to [CRAN Task View: Optimization and Mathematical Programming](https://https:/https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), the problem can be approached by several optimisation methods, i.e. there are methods which let $P$ be positive semidefinite.

I do not understand, is there guarantee that a solution (one of, if there are many) found by the methods will provide the minimum of the objective function?

Comment: When $P$ is SPD, the problem is convex (not strictly convex): https://brickisland.net/cs177/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/ddg_definiteness.svg
In that case, there may be infinitely many minima (depending on the constraints), all global because they all have the same objective value.

Comment: Dear @CharlieVanaret , I understand that. The question is that if those algorithms which can deal with $P$ positive semidefinite give a solution which is one of those global ones?

Comment: Well the problem is convex, so you just need to find a minimum, it will be global (but not necessarily unique).